# Unable to derive an inequality related to integrals

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, logarithms, integral-inequality

I am unable to think on how to derive this inequality. 
Can someone please help!!

Inequality is -> $\int_1^n logx dx$ $\leq$ log(n!) $\int_2^{n+1} logx dx $ .

I tried using Integration by parts of logx , applying limits and then comparing with log(n!) but that doesn't seems to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evaluate the first integral to get

$$\int_1^n \log x \:dx = x\log x - x \Bigr|_1^n = n\log n - n + 1$$

then by Stirling's approximation we have that

$$n\log n - n + 1 \leq \log(n!)$$

and the integral on the right is greater than $1$, giving the desired inequality.